# How to reload the current component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've have an component "A" with a button. When the user press the button I'm showing a modal(react-responsive-modal) with bunch of filed and an update button. When the user presses the update button on the modal I want to reload the component "A" with the updated data.

I tried redirecting using `this.props.history.push('dashboard/componentA')` but it didn't work. Then I tried redirecting to the dashboard and again redirecting to the component like this

```
this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
this.props.history.push('/dashboard/componentA');
```

It worked but I'm not seeing any loader that I've used on 'componentWillMount' and the component just freezes up. I couldn't scroll up or down.

Comment: update its state maybe?

Comment: @Danyallmran yeah I could update the state with updated data but I want to reload the whole component for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use the browser history as a way to update react (as much as you can). React is designed to re-render components when the props or state for that component change. As an example, this should trigger an update in `ComponentA` without needing to update the browser's history:

```js
class ComponentA extends Component {
  handleModalClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      componentData: event.data,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactModal onClick={this.handleClick} />
    )
  }
}
```

EDIT: Updated to show a data fetching parent component:

```js
class DataFetcher extends Component {
  saveAndFetchData = (saveData) => {
    FetchDataPromise(saveData).then((updatedData) => {
      this.setState({ data: updatedData });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentA data={data} />
        <ReactModalComponent handleClick={saveAndFetchData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ComponentA extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        ...render data...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My Modal is actually in separate component, passing the data from it to the parent component needs to dispatch another action after the data has been saved to the database. I'm not sure if there's any way to reload the whole component instead of re-rendering it by changing the current state of component.

Comment: In that case, I'd typically have a dataFetching component that wraps ComponentA and injects data into it. You could then have a promise in that parent component call a `setState` on the parent, which would update the data in `ComponentA` causing a full-rerender of ComponentA.

Comment: Even if the modal is in a separate component, as long as the `DataFetcher` component is the parent to both ComponentA and the component that holds the modal, this should work.

Comment: Yeah I've done something similar. But the backend API that is providing data to `componentA` is really complicated and I don't think it's better to repeat the code in update endpoint as well.  Maybe I could re-fetch the data once I get success response and change the state accordingly. Right?

Comment: Yup that's what I would do. Just have the save endpoint send back a simple response and when you get that do a fetch for the updated data.